# What is the cost of `multiple` JOINs of single table, in order to have variable columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I need to have variable columns in a Mysql database. I use an alternative which is to have a helper `meta_data` table. I store variable columns in each row of `meta_data`. The structure of `meta_data` is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_meta` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_key` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `data_id` (`data_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=347 ;
```

I need to query on some of those variable columns. So my question is What is the cost of such statement in Mysql:

```
select * 
from data
join data_meta as data_prov on (data.id=data_prov.data_id)
join data_meta as data_city on (data.id=data_city.data_id)
join data_meta as data_price on (data.id=data_price.data_id)
.
.
.
.
```

If in real world, this can cause my query to be really slow, is there any alternatives for having `variable columns` ?

**Note**:Both `data` and `meta_data` can grow rapidly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is indexed correctly, then the multiple joins should not be a problem.  In this case, you want an index on `data_meta(data_id, meta_key)` or even `data_meta(data_id, meta_key, meta_value)`

By the way, I think you left the `meta_key` out of the logic

```
select * 
from data
join data_meta as data_prov on (data.id=data_prov.data_id and data_prov.meta_key = 'prov')
join data_meta as data_city on (data.id=data_city.data_id and data_city.meta_key = 'city')
join data_meta as data_price on (data.id=data_price.data_id and data_price.meta_key = 'price')
```

Assuming you only have one match per key, you can also do the query as:

```
select d.*,
       max(case when dm.meta_key = 'prov' then dm.meta_value end) as prov,
       . . .
from data join
     data_meta dm
     on d.id = dm.id
group by d.id;
```

If you are fetching the values for one meta key, this would be fine.  However, MySQL tends to do joins faster than aggregation, so the join method is probably faster in general.

EDIT:

For this query to work quickly, you need to be able to lookup the meta values quickly.  In MySQL, the best way to do this is using an index.  This allows MySQL to lookup the values in the meta data quickly.  Other databases support a technology called parallel hash joins, which would also speed up the query (and parallel hash aggregation would speed up the group by).  By these are not options in MySQL, so you want to use indexing.

Comment: Can you please explain more about indexing affect?

Comment: Can I get ALL meta_values automatically in just one query? Or the only way for me is to use PHP to create my query each time?

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy . . . You could get all meta values by using `group_concat()`.